# How to outsmart ExpressionEngine Parse Order?

Tags: plugin, parse-order

I need to get this work — how can I code this to get the parse-order I need?

`{exp:channel:entries channel='{exp:plugin entry_id="{segment_3}"}' …`

As you can see in the code above: I read out the 3rd segment of the url, paste it in a attr of a plugin and use its output as a value of the channel-attr of exp:channel:entries.

Right now it does not work, the plugin with the segment-readout does work outside of the exp:channel:entries-Tag, therefore I *think* it is a parse order issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put exp:channel:entries inside **embeded**  template

```
{embed="site/channel" my_plugin_ids="{exp:plugin entry_id="{segment_3}"}
```

*site/channel*

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='{embed:my_plugin_ids}' …
```

-or-

put exp:channel:entries inside your plugin tag's

```
{exp:plugin entry_id="{segment_3}" parse="inward"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel='{my_plugin_ids}' …

{/exp:plugin}
```

Comment: … use embeds … omg, I've been away from active developing for to long! :-) THX Max!